# Running Java Program linking to thirdpary library (java -jar) issue ( Multiple methods tried )

Tags: java, classpath, javac

This issue is related to running a Java program (jar) dependent on thirdparty jar library even after setting classpath and trying so many other methods by reading articles in Internet.

I want to use a thirdparty Pack1.jar (it is not a part of jvm) as dependency of my programme.
I do not know where the Pack1.jar file could be in the deployment machine and I want the deployer to specify the path for the thirdparty libraries

I have tried the following alternatives in vain

1. Setting the java.class.path programatically

   ```
   String class_path = args[0];
   System.setProperty("java.class.path",class_path);
   ```

   Here I am assuming that deployer would supply the classpath as first argument while running the program
2. Setting the CLASSPATH env_var to locate the thirdparty directory
3. While running, using the classpath option

   ```
   java -classpath /path/to/Pack1.jar -jar Pack2.jar
   ```

   I think this would not work because documentation says that classpath is ignored when program is run with "java -jar"
4. Setting the java.ext.dirs programatically.
5. Setting the java.library.path programatically.

I do not want to specify the Class-Path in manifest because that takes only relative path and I do not know where the thirdparty library would be kept in deployment machine

But I am unable to get the jar running.

How can I fix this problem any help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go for option 3. Put both jars on the classpath like this:

```
java -classpath '/path/to/Pack1.jar:/path/to/Pack2.jar' com.packagename.yourclassname
```

Note, that this is for Linux. on Windows, you would separate classpath elements with semicolons:

```
java -classpath "/path/to/Pack1.jar;/path/to/Pack2.jar" com.packagename.yourclassname
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29

Comment: That would require one to know the entry point, Is'nt there a way to run with -jar option and also specify the location of the thirdparty libraries ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Pack2.jar` without running it using `-jar`--put it on the classpath and call the entry point listed in its manifest file.

I usually wrap that up in a launcher script to avoid those kinds of problems, and allow jar paths to be set using an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Name the secondary JAR(s) in the Class-path entry of the Manifest.MF of the main JAR file, and use java -jar.

Your objection to this technique doesn't make sense. If you supply and deploy the secondary JAR files, as you should, you have the same degree of control over their location as you do over that of the major JAR file. It doesn't matter where else the user may have copies of them.